# Single page application using Angularjs and ui.router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to make a single page application using Angularjs and ui.router,
but my code not working.

**index.html:**

```
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.9" data-semver="1.4.9" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="uirouter.js"></script>
    <script src="route.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div  ui-view></div>
    <script src="NABHController.js"></script>
     <script src="nabh1Controller.js"></script>
      <script src="nabh2Controller.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

**route.js:**

```
var compliance=angular.module('ikomplianzNABH',['ui.router']);
compliance.run(function($rootScope, $state) {
      $rootScope.$state = $state;
    });
compliance.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
    .state('/', { /*....This state defines All type of user login...*/
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'NABH.html',
        controller: 'NABHController'
    })
    .state('.nabh1', { /*....This state defines All type of user login...*/
        url: '/nabh1',
        templateUrl: 'nabh1.html',
        controller: 'nabh1Controller'
    })
    .state('.nabh2', { /*....This state defines All type of user login...*/
        url: '/nabh2',
        templateUrl: 'nabh2.html',
        controller: 'nabh2Controller'
    })
});
```

Here when user is typing the URL `http://localhost/test/` the `NABH.html` page should render. inisde this file there is one link to route to another page but this page should render inside that `NABH.html ui-view` instead of index page.

**NABH.html:**

```
<div> 
<div ui-view>
<div class="clecklist">
<a ui-sref=".nabh2">Click Me</a>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

When user will click on `Click Me` the `nabh2.html` should render into this page.

**nabh2.html:**

```
h1>{{msg}}</h1>
```

In my case nothing is happening. Here only I need to set `NABH.html` as parent view and both `nabh1.html,nabh2.html` should used as its child view. [My full Plunkr code](https://plnkr.co/edit/wnShcvepuaUshcidpE22?p=preview) is here.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion for an alternative: Another option entirely is using [ng-include](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_includes.asp).

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="controller.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="nabhController">
      <div>
        <label>{{message}}</label>
      </div>

      <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

NABH.html:

```
<div ng-controller="nabhController"> 
  <div class="checklist">
    <div>
       <button ng-click="showNabh =! showNabh">Click Me</button>
     </div>

     <div ng-show="showNabh">
       <div ng-include="'nabh1.html'"></div>
     </div>
     <div ng-show="!showNabh">
       <div ng-include="'nabh2.html'"></div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

NABH1.html

```
<div ng-controller="nabh1Controller">
  {{message}}
</div>
```

NABH2.html

```
<div ng-controller="nabh2Controller">
  <h1>{{message}}</h1>
</div>
```

Controller

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('nabhController', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = "Welcome";
  $scope.showNabh = false;
});

app.controller('nabh1Controller', function($scope){
  $scope.message = "Nabh1"
});

app.controller('nabh2Controller', function($scope){
  $scope.message = "Nabh2"
});

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when("/", {
        templateUrl: 'nabh.html',
        controller: 'nabhController'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
});
```

---

**[Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/zQ7lis7q2DhxXOz7GOZ4/)**

Comment: For both can we use different controller ? I could not get `showNabh != showNabh`. Can you please edit that plunkr with your code ?

Comment: How the route file will execute ?

Comment: Added a plunk for you.

Comment: I want to add the click inside `nabh2.html` page not in that common page.

Comment: I added but it was not working  means `<div>
       <button ng-click="showNabh =! showNabh">Click Me</button>
     </div>` inside the nabh2.html page.\

Comment: Add this to nabh2.html to have the button work there: `<div><button ng-click="$parent.showNabh =! $parent.showNabh">Click Me</button></div>`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one of two ways:

**First Way:**

```
var compliance=angular.module('ikomplianzNABH',['ui.router', 'ngSanitize']);
compliance.run(function($rootScope, $state) {
      $rootScope.$state = $state;
    });
compliance.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
    .state('/', { /*....This state defines All type of user login...*/
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'NABH.html',
        controller: 'NABHController'
    })
    .state('.nabh1', { /*....This state defines All type of user login...*/
        url: '/nabh1',
        templateUrl: 'nabh1.html',
        controller: 'nabh1Controller'
    })
    .state('.nabh2', { /*....This state defines All type of user login...*/
        url: '/nabh2',
        templateUrl: 'nabh2.html',
        controller: 'nabh2Controller'
    })
});


var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('nabhController', function($scope) {
  $scope.$sce = $sce;
  $scope.message = "Welcome";
  $scope.showNabh = false;
});

    app.controller('nabh1Controller', function($scope){
      $scope.message = "Nabh1"
    });

    app.controller('nabh2Controller', function($scope, $sce){
      $scope.message = "Nabh2"
    });

    app.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
          .when("/", {
            templateUrl: 'nabh.html',
            controller: 'nabhController'
          })
          .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
          });
    });

<div> 
<div ui-view>
<div class="clecklist">
<a ng-bind-html="$sce.trustAsHtml(.nabh2.html)">Click Me</a>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

**Second Way**:

```
 <div> 
    <div ui-view>
    <div class="clecklist">
    <a ng-click="TakeMeToLink()">Click Me</a>
    </div>
    </div>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('nabhController', function($scope, $location) {
  $scope.$sce = $sce;
  $scope.message = "Welcome";
  $scope.showNabh = false;

 $scope.TakeMeToLinh = function() {
       $location.path("/nabh2");
    };
});

    app.controller('nabh1Controller', function($scope){
      $scope.message = "Nabh1"
    });

    app.controller('nabh2Controller', function($scope, $sce){
      $scope.message = "Nabh2"
    });

    app.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
          .when("/", {
            templateUrl: 'nabh.html',
            controller: 'nabhController'
          })
          .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
          });
    });
```